# Pressing left mousebutton

Tags: javascript

I am looking to make a javascript code that can be put in the google console. This code should press the left button at a really high speed. I tried with a code like this:

```
var event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    key: 'g',
    ctrlKey: true
});

setInterval(function(){
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}, 0);
```

This code only presses G. Now my problem is what defination makes it press the left mouse button.
What should I replace G with to make it press the left mouse button? This code will be used to "cheat" in capybara clicker!
Capy bara clicker: https://www.crazygames.com/game/capybara-clicker-2

Thanks, Ivar!

I tried this code, and it didnt work. I want this code to instead of pressing g at a fast rate, it should press the left mouse button!

```
var event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    key: 'g',
    ctrlKey: true
});

setInterval(function(){
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}, 0);
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need to automate a keypress and not just what should happen when that key is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You want a mouse event.

```
let event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    button: 0, // Left button is represented by 0
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
});
const element = document.querySelector('what you want to click');
setInterval(function(){
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}, 0); //  execute "immediately", or more accurately, the next event cycle.
```

You MAY want to change the 0 to something else since the game might have a debounce on the click

I tested this code on google's homepage - it clicks many times (but of course only one click is needed here)

```
let event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    button: 0, // Left button is represented by 0
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
});
const btn = document.querySelector('[aria-label="I\'m Feeling Lucky"]')
setInterval(function(){
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    btn.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}, 0);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `0` be a valid delay timeout, since internally when omitting the parameter, the delay is set to 0 as well. And basically tells the browser to make the delay as short as the browser allows?

Comment: Hello again!
I tried it again, with your code. And it didnt make it click. 
I tried in some other clicking games and it didnt work their either.

Comment: See update. You need to click something in the page

Comment: I tried the code on googles home page.
In the console it came up with a lot a "error"

5601VM108:9  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dispatchEvent')
    at <anonymous>:9:9

And the numbers at the beginning were just counting up at a really fast rate. But when putting it over a "button" the action that the button should make was not made (It didnt click the button)

Comment: When I did it, it of course gave errors since only one click is registered and the page is then unloaded. but it DID go to "I'm feeling lucky"

Comment: I can try when I come home.. I do not want to load Capybara games at work.